# show draft posts to author wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, status, author

I am creating custom post types from front-end.I have created some role using **add_role** e.g manager

This manager is creating custom post type (e.g contest).I am saving all contests as **Draft**
and then admin publish them.

But I want to show preview to manager when he creates contest.When I am viewing that post it is showing 404 while when admin previews it works.

Please help me how to show draft post to author who is creating it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [How to let someone preview a draft?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/42733/12615)